# GTIFF_SRS_SOURCE configuration

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I have a function that worked *(and still does the business)* but now prints a `warning`

```py
OutTile = gdal.Warp(outFile, 
                    inFile, 
                    dstSRS=outCRS,
                    outputBounds = [minX, minY, maxX, maxY])
OutTile = None
```

`Warning 1: The definition of geographic CRS EPSG:4326 got from GeoTIFF keys is not the same as the one from the EPSG registry, which may cause issues during reprojection operations. Set GTIFF_SRS_SOURCE configuration option to EPSG to use official parameters (overriding the ones from GeoTIFF keys), or to GEOKEYS to use custom values from GeoTIFF keys and drop the EPSG code.`

The projection is:

```py
ds = gdal.Open(inFile)
prj = ds.GetProjection()
print(prj)
```

`PROJCS["",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223600004,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",19],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]`

What do I need to plug into the original function please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to quiet the warning add

```
 gdal.SetConfigOption("GTIFF_SRS_SOURCE", "EPSG")
```

EPSG:4326 is so well defined that I do not believe that there is any real risk of wrong transformation. You can test it by creating test outputs with values "EPSG" and "GEOKEYS". The warning means that the GeoTIFF tags which are stored into the image file are in some way different to the parameters of EPSG:4326 in the current EPSG database.

```
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
        AREA["World."],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

Comment: Thank you @user30184. Would 'srcSRS' silence the warning? If I add 'srcSRS=prj' to the original function; will it define the source projection and silence the warning? ---it takes me a long time to start python and although I love experimenting; if I can save some time it would be appreciated.